# How can I update certain value by searching another child value?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm making an app on Android Studio 
using firebase and I have a problem with updating a data.

I'm trying to update a child by searching another child which has certain value that I will give as a parameter.

[image]

This is my structure and I want to update `dailyRank` to 2 where `dailyTotalDis` is 5.8.

Here's some code that I wrote.

```
 FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
 ref = database.getReference("RECORD");

 String check = "dailyData/1557360000000/";
 ref.child(check).child("dailyTotalDis").equalTo("5.8").setValue("1");
```

I'm sure my code has a problem but I have no idea how to approach differently.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to update `dailyRank` based on `dailyTotalDis` value, then try the following:

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
ref = database.getReference("RECORD");
String check = "CTJZNO5pU2RzlAQa7ol5OlQoTmU2/dailyData/1557360000000/";

ref.child(check).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
 @Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
   Integer value = dataSnapshot.child("dailyTotalDis").getValue(Integer.class);
   if(value.equalsTo(5.8))
        ref.child(check).child("dailyRank").setValue("1");
}

@Override
public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
  }
});
```

First, get the reference to your node, then retrieve the value of `dailyTotalDis` and update `dailyRank` if it satisfies the condition.